# Retrieve the Flavor and BuildType dependent class path within gradle script

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am attempting to generate JNI headers using the 'javah' command and to do so I need to pass the directory which contains the project .class files. Previously with ant this was a static location, but it is dynamic with buildTypes and productFlavors on gradle.

Is there a variable in gradle which represents the class path? For instance I want to retrieve build/intermediates/classes/debug/, build/intermediates/classes/dev/debug/, etc.

I am on gradle 1.2.3, I have attempted to use 'sourceSets.main.output.classesdir' but I get an error that 'output' could not be found on source set main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a straightforward way to determine the buildType and productFlavor dynamically, but I found a solution via examining the task graph.

```
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
        if (taskGraph.hasTask(assembleRelease)) {
            buildTypeClassPath = "build/intermediates/classes/release"
        } else {
            buildTypeClassPath = "build/intermediates/classes/debug"
        }
    }
```

I think this solution can be adapted to incorporate productFlavors by changing the check for hasTask(assembleRelease) into hasTask(assembleProdRelease)